# Reversar deshacer cambios en VSCode

Tags: visual-studio

Mi error novato fue no haber realizado commit de mis avances. Resulta que hice varios cambios en la aplicación y me genero errores. Y se me hizo fácil poder deshacer cambios y entre esos se perdieron mis avances.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y como pueden observar en la img que pongo de ejemplo es el archivo ComponenteInputDisabled.js si de lo doy en la 2da opción quitar los cambios y no vuelve a aparece el archivo.

Hay algún solución recuperar estos archivos desechos, ya que no tiene commit :(
O por lo visto tendre que empezar nuevamente a realizar desde 0 en esta parte

Answer (score 1):

> Tenes ademas de lo que comento herramientas graficas adicionales como

[Git GUI](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/)
y Especificamente para **VSC** podes instalar la **extencion** que mas te agrade entre ellas **Git History y  Git Graph**
**Git History** extensión que te permite explorar de forma profunda al historial de un archivo, un autor concreto, una rama y demas Para activar  Git History hacer clic con el botón derecho sobre un archivo podes hacerlo con el que tenes conflictivo  y seleccionar **Git: View File History:**

> El comando git status mustra el historial mostrando el estado del
> directorio de trabajo y del área del entorno de ensayo. muestra lo que
> ha ocurrido con los comandos git add y git commit dando informacion
> sobre la rama actual

```js
$ git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    README
```

[git status --verbose](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status)
Puedes ver que el archivo README está sin rastrear porque aparece debajo del encabezado
“Untracked files” . Sin rastrear significa que Git si puede ver archivos que no
tenías en el commit anterior. Asi Git no los incluirá en tu próximo commit
Puede haber ocurrido que tengas archivos sin rastrear
entonces hacer git add README en este caso
[[tutorial control verciones](https://www.ionos.es/digitalguide/paginas-web/desarrollo-web/tutorial-de-git/)][3](https://www.ionos.es/digitalguide/paginas-web/desarrollo-web/tutorial-de-git/)
Puedes revisar historial con

```js
git reflog
```

Ver graficanente commits con

```js
git log --graph --decorate --oneline
*   158e71d (HEAD -> main, origin/main) Merge branch 'main' of https://github.com/nestdanchia/NgZone
|\
| * 88fc9cf Update card.component.ts
* | 509640d grid
|/
```

Para restaurar archivos del arbol de trabajo que fueron confirmados

volver sin descartar

```js
git checkout hashCommitAnterior.
```

Volver y Descartar cambios 5 ultimos

```js
git reset --hard HEAD~5
```

El comando git revert deshará el commit que le hemos indicado, pero creará un nuevo commit deshaciendo la anterior
git revert  158e71....
seguiras viendo todos los commits incluso los revertidos
Para ver diferencias

```js
git diff HEAD mars.txt
```

otros comandos [git commit --amend](https://www.atlassian.com/es/git/tutorials/rewriting-history)